# Formatting Script For Automated Email in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am a restaurant owner trying to automate the creation of a message to my employees using google spreadsheets.

I have this:

```
=E2&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Here are your tip numbers:"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Cash Tips: "&I2&" Credit Card Tips: "&J2&" Form 4070's are due in the office by 4pm Wednesday and they are required by law from every tipped employee.  Thank you. -- Management Team"
```

Here are the cell values:

```
E2 = "Ron"
I2 = "19"
J2 = "25"
```

Currently, it looks like this:

> Ron
>
> Here are your tip numbers:
>
> Cash Tips 19 Credit Card Tips: 25 Form 4070's are due in the office by 4pm Wednesday and they are required by law from every tipped employee.  Thank you. -- Management Team

But I would like it to be formatted like this:

> Ron,
>
> Here are your tip numbers:
>
> **Cash Tips:** $19
>
> **Credit Card Tips:** $25
>
> Form 4070's are due in the office by 4pm Wednesday and they are required by law from every tipped employee.
>
> Thank you.
>
> -- Management Team

Can anyone help an old guy out who has zero experience doing this?

So, I am looking for:

- 1. A comma after "Ron"
- 2. "Cash Tips:" in BOLD letters
- 3. "Credit Card Tips:" in BOLD letters
- 4. A "$" sign before the number in the I2 and J2 fields
- 5. Lines skipped as noted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial formatting, for the bold, is unavailable at this time.

This takes care of the rest though:

```
=E2&","&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Here are your tip numbers:"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Cash Tips: "&"$"&I2&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Credit Card Tips: "&"$"&J2&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Form 4070's are due in the office by 4pm Wednesday and they are required by law from every tipped employee."&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Thank you."&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"-- Management Team"
```

**Update to accommodate the rounding of currency values to 2 decimal places:**

```
=E2&","&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Here are your tip numbers:"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Cash Tips: "&"$"&ROUND(I2, 2)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Credit Card Tips: "&"$"&ROUND(J2, 2)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Form 4070's are due in the office by 4pm Wednesday and they are required by law from every tipped employee."&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Thank you."&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"-- Management Team"
```

Comment: Hello again, the code you gave me works perfectly except for one thing -- it is putting the dollar figures into the emails with 8 numbers to the right of the decimal.  For example, if it is supposed to pull in $92.38 it will pull something like $92.38234567.  Can you advise me on how to limit the number in the email to two numbers to the right of the decimal?  Your help is truly appreciated (and you pizza is getting cold!)!

Comment: @RonBrown I updated the answer. Let me know if that worked out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I realize this is easy for you, but it is like magic for me and I am so grateful for your help.

Comment: It's me again with another question.  I have this code in the script editor of my google spreadsheet:

Comment: function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 35;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B36
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 36)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Tips for Pay Period 9/12/2015 - 9/25/2015";

Comment: last line I had to leave out because of character limitations:    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}

Comment: Is there a way to change that so that if the dollar numbers are ZERO it will not send an email?

Comment: Before I provide the answer I just need to verify some data... Are `I` and `J` the correct columns for the dollar amounts? That would make that data appear in your `for` loop as `row[8]` and `row[9]`, respectively. Also, do you want to NOT SEND when BOTH values are 0, or when EITHER value is 0?

Comment: Yes, I and J are the correct columns for the dollar amounts.  And, I want to NOT SEND an email when BOTH values are 0.  Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other information in order to answer my question.  Thanks again.

Comment: I hope you can answer my question.  Thanks!